# Node.js Recursion and Memory Limit

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory, recursion

I am attempting to scrape data of a website and I am using node.js to do this as it seemed like a good idea to use javascript to handle traversing the DOM of a webpage.

The problem I have encountered is that I don't want to hit the web server too fast for obvious reason, so I put in a time delay using recursion. However after about 10,000 records I hit the memory limit of node.js. There are 17,000 records in total right now.

```
var i = 0;                     //  set your counter to 1

function myLoop (n) {           //  create a loop function
   setTimeout(function () {    //  call a 1s setTimeout when the loop is called
     request(url, function(error, response, html){
         if(!error){
     }

     }) ;
      i++;                     //  increment the counter
      if (i < ids.length) {    //  if the counter < ids.length, call the loop function
         myLoop();             //  ..  again which will trigger another
      }                        //  ..  setTimeout()
   }, 2000)
}

myLoop();                      //  start the loop
```

Above is a the recursion loop used in the code. I used recursion because request is asynchronous and timeout is non stopping of for loops.

The solution that I used for the time being was to run it twice and copy and paste the outputs together. There must be a better way to do this.

Here is a complete version of the code (anonymized)

```
var express = require('express');
var fs = require('fs');
var request = require('request');
var cheerio = require('cheerio');
var json2csv = require('json2csv');

console.log('Starting');

ids = []

count = -1;

fs.readFile('data.csv', 'utf-8', function (err,data) {
  if (err) {
    return console.log(err);
  }
  console.log('### CSV data incoming ###');
  console.log();
  console.log(data);
  console.log('### End of CSV data ###');
  ids = data.split('\n');
});

var jsonFinal = new Array();

var i = 0;                     //  set your counter to 1

function myLoop (n) {           //  create a loop function
   setTimeout(function () {    //  call a 1s setTimeout when the loop is called
     console.log('for loop ' + i);

     url = 'http://www.example.org.uk/location/' + ids[i];

     request(url, function(error, response, html){
         if(!error){
         var $ = cheerio.load(html);

         var example1, example2, example3, example4, example5;
         var json = {uid : "", name : "", example1 : "", example2 : "", example3 : "", example4 : "", example5 : ""};

         //Traverse DOM here

         jsonFinal.push(json);
         count += 1;
         console.log('Pushed JSON array ' + count)
         if (count+1 == ids.length){
           // To write to the system we will use the built in 'fs' library.
           // In this example we will pass 3 parameters to the writeFile function
           // Parameter 1 :  output.json - this is what the created filename will be called
           // Parameter 2 :  JSON.stringify(json, null, 4) - the data to write, here we do an extra step by calling JSON.stringify to make our JSON easier to read
           // Parameter 3 :  callback function - a callback function to let us know the status of our function

           //fields for the csv
           var fields = ['uid', 'name', 'example1', 'example2', 'example3', 'example4', 'example5'];

           fs.writeFile('output.json', JSON.stringify(jsonFinal, null, 4), function(err){

               console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.json file');

           })
           json2csv({ data: jsonFinal, fields: fields }, function(err, csv) {
             if (err) console.log(err);
             fs.writeFile('output.csv', csv, function(err) {
               if (err) throw err;
               console.log('File successfully written! - Check your project directory for the output.csv file');
             });
           });
         }
     }

     }) ;
      i++;                     //  increment the counter
      if (i < ids.length) {    //  if the counter < ids.length, call the loop function
         myLoop();             //  ..  again which will trigger another
      }                        //  ..  setTimeout()
   }, 2000)
}

myLoop();                      //  start the loop
```

Answer (score 0):

Just move the recursive call to the request's callback, to not hurt the stack

```
i++;                     //  increment the counter

request(url, function(error, response, html){

    if (i < ids.length) {    //  if the counter < ids.length, call the loop function
        myLoop();             //  ..  again which will trigger another
    }
    // ...
    if(!error){
        // ...
    }
}) ;
```

Comment: The call is already in the `setTimeout` callback and will not overflow the stack.